# Access latency's of request methods within Spring based controller

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have various web services return data to user :

Pseudo-code :

```
MyController {

SoapRequest1 {
 processRequest
 return data1
}

SoapRequest2 {
 return data2
}

}
```

I wish to monitor the performance of these requests individually. This is what I'm considering :

Pseudo-code :

```
MyController {

List latency

SoapRequest1 {
 timeStamp1
 processRequest
 return data1
 latency.add(timeStamp2 - timeStamp1)
 timeStamp2
}

SoapRequest2 {
 timeStamp1
 processRequest
 timeStamp2
 latency.add(timeStamp2 - timeStamp1)
 return data2
}

getRequestLatencies{
  return latency
}
}
```

So then to access the latency's of the requests at any time I can just call `getRequestLatencies`. These is just a high level but I think this should work. Further work is required to filter the specific latency's but at a high level is this sufficient ? I do not like having to modify the controller to access the latency's for each request but I don't know of any other method ? Is there a design pattern I am not aware of ?

The latency's will need to be access from a UI front end. So I will be exposing the latency values via a service.

Comment: Cant you use AOP ? Check this stackoverflow.com/questions/1496205/… Answer

Comment: try applying an aspect to the controller methods you want to monitor, and log the timings to a separate log file with a separate log4j appender

Comment: one way would be besides the aspect logging to a file, have the aspect also insert timings in a database table. Then the statistics service can query that table for metrics

Answer (score 0):

We use Servlet Filters here to achieve basically the same result.  I'm pretty sure Spring MVC has its own Filter concept.  The concept is to start a stopwatch on the inbound side stop and record it as the response goes outbound.  Expose this kid through JMX MBean or something and now you're monitoring it with only an hour or two of work.  Works like a champ.

The challenge then becomes not keeping track of the latency but "classifying" the request as the filter grabs all the requests and you usually need to know stuff like "/somerequest2 averages 2ms while /somerequest3 averages 8ms".  List of compiled regex'es here with some "catch all" to handle the case where we have some API that we don't care much about.

Primitive, but effective.

Comment: I guess I'm not fully onboard with the Controller simply maintaining a List of timings.  At the very least you lose the differences between SoapRequest1 and SoapRequest2 this way.  I also somewhat agree with the guy that you don't want to litter up your Business Logic with your performance measurements.  We've gone the "Patterns in Filter" route to address both of these issues.  I'm sure there is a way you could leverage Java Annotations here as well to get something like a mix-in of latency monitoring.  I like the Filters solution best.  Its "up the middle and no surprises".

Comment: This guy suggests there is a Spring plug-in to do something like this with annotations:  http://javasight.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/monitoring-with-spring-and-jamon-using-jamonperformancemonitorinterceptor/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is good design to mix (performance) monitoring and business code - I would prefer an external monitoring solution/code where you either monitor the service locally (from the same server) to prevent network latency or monitor the service using your actual network connection to test network latency. In both cases, the logic for latency calculation would happen right before and after the method call.

**EDIT** I am not experienced in spring controllers, but do you need any special configuration to run your controllers, like a container or something?